# Filter using check boxes

Tags: filter, checkbox

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this problem but have yet to find one.

I have a form whereby a user can filter Recipes by type and meal time. There are 10 types and 4 meal times. They are all check boxes.

What I need to happen is that when a user selects multiple types/meals they are return with filtered entries.

I have looked into dynamic parameters but it only allows one 'type' and one 'meal time' to be returned and isn't ideal.

I did consider using segments but it would result in a long URL which I would have to use PHP on to separate 'types'/'meals times'. I also considered using POST but it didn't work as expected.

Will I have to resort to Vanilla PHP for this and if so can someone provide a few pointers.

Thanks

Comment: I had to do something like this before. The types and meals have to be fields or they can be categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low Search
http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search

Assuming your types/times are categories (which it sounds like they are)...

In your `{exp:low_search:results}` tag, you should use `require_all="category"`. This will make sure the results only match entries with *all* the selected categories.

Your checkboxes should all be named `category[]`.

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="recipes" style="linear"}
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="{category_id}"{if category_id IN ({low_search_category})} checked{/if}> {category_name}</label>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to use PHP. You can create an Extension or Module and an [ACTion URL](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/modules.html#update-file-function-reference) to keep it clean. EE was not designed to handle this much data in an "SEO-friendly" or non-programmatic manner.